# How To Loop with mkvtoolnix with multiple extension

Tags: mkvtoolnix

---

- I want to merge some different extension file into one file
- for example I have three files "ENG S01E01.ac3" "ENG S01E01.eac3" "ENG
  S01E01.ass"
- I tried some loop cmd for i in *{ac3,eac3,ass}; do
  mkvmerge -o "${i%.*}.mka" "$i"; done But it's result only one stream
  contain Please anyone know!

---

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.